# a property of infinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

An infinite matrix $[a_{ij}]_{i,j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is called *invertible*, if for any convergent sequence $(y_m)$ there exists exactly one sequence $(x_m)$ such that $y_m=\sum_{n\ge 1}a_{mn}x_n$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Find two infinite invertible matrices $A,B$ such that $AB$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about these two?

$A=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&1&1&1&1&\cdots\\
0&1&0&0&0&\cdots\\
0&0&1&0&0&\cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}\right]$

and

$B=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&0&0&0&0&\cdots\\
-1&1&0&0&0&\cdots\\
0&-1&1&0&0&\cdots\\
0&0&-1&1&0&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{array}\right]$

Then the entire first row of $AB$ is zeros so it cannot be invertible.  But I believe both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.  If you write down the equations from the first one we have $x_n=y_n$ for all $n>1$ and $x_1=y_1-\sum_{n\geq2}y_n$.  And from the second one $x_1=y_1$, $x_2=y_2+y_1$, $x_3=y_3+y_2+y_1$, etc.  So both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.